# How can i display images using <img> in simple HTML 5 files?

Tags: html, image

My question is ow can i display images using `<img>` tag in simple HTML 5 files?

I tried the **test.html** shown file below with my wampserver both online and offline. But the result was almost same.

File paths are

```
C:\wamp\www\fluid\SMS\test\test.html
C:\wamp\www\fluid\SMS\test\stack.jpg
C|/Users/aimme/Desktop/stack.jpg
```

Here is the **test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- works on internet explorer
         doesn't work on other ff & chrome -->
         <img src="file:///C|/Users/aimme/Desktop/stack.jpg" alt="stack img from my desktop" width="500" height="100"/>
         <!--doesn't work on ie,ff or chrome-->
         <img src="stack.png" alt="stack img from same folder" width="100" height="100"/>
         <!--doesn't work on ie,ff or chrome-->
         <img src="cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" alt="stack img from site" height="100" width="100">
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the results.

How this is seen in Internet explorer version 11.0.9600.17031
[image: internet explorer 11.0.9600.17031]
How this is seen in firefox 40.0.3
[image]
How this is seen in chrome 47.0.2503.0 dev-m (64-bit)
[image]

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- I suspect Chrome and FF don't like the pipe character in `"file:///C|/Users/aimme/Desktop/stack.jpg"`, which is why it fails there.
- If your file is named `stack.jpg`, you need to include the `.jpg` extension for it to work.
- You want to use the protocol in your remote URL, or it'll be treated as relative:  `<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png" alt="stack img from site" height="100" width="100">`

Comment: edited my question. extension added but doesn't work :)

Comment: i tried everything u said before posting this question, but it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no closing tag. It's one of the few elements that doesn't use them.

```
<img src="Desktop/stack.jpg" class="flr" alt="Lake Atitlan, Guatemala" width="300" height="240">
```

Provide relative path to image.

For more detail please refer following link:

http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/image-element.htm

Comment: it's no error if you add `/` before the end of  the tag

Comment: Try to put image in same directory as the HTML file and give the relative path to the src property.

Comment: i don't think its much of a concern in html 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<img src="stack.jpg" />
```

With the file stack.jpg in the same directory as the HTML file.

For remote files put in the complete URL i.e. http://...